# To go hitch-hiking or to go for hitch-hiking

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

Which one is correct to use ?

> The bank manger was given a holiday and he resolved to go hitch-hiking.

Or

> The back manager was given a holiday and he resolved to go for hitch-hiking.

Comment: As a side note, hitchhiking is commonly a single word without the hyphen.  Also, (at least in the United States) it's generally considered a disreputable activity and unlikely to be something a bank manager would do, unless for some reason he didn't care about his reputation.

Answer (score 1):

To *hitch-hike* is a verb.

So people go hitch-hiking in the same way that they go swimming or climbing or similar, where the verb appears as a gerund.

On the other hand, one goes *for* a swim or a climb.

That's to say, where nouns are concerned, *one goes for something*.
Where gerunds are concerned, *one goes sailing/singing/hitch-hiking* or whatever.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't think hitchhike is one of those words that also works as a noun.  I've never heard of someone go for a hitchhike.  But the answer is otherwise conceptually right.

Comment: @fixer1234 Agreed. I didn't mean to propose it as a noun (although I see that dictionary.com allows it) http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hitchhike